# How output my input type in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table type variable in my database called `type_first`.

I need to pass this type as input parameter to my stored procedure, then delete some records from that, and after that pass `type_first` as output.

My code is like this:

```
create procedure dbo._sp_checkId
    @value dbo.type_first readonly
as
    delete from @value
    where Id in (select Id
                 from dbo.tbl_first)
```

I need to output `@value` after delete, but I am not allowed because variable names must be unique in a query.

I do not want to declare another type in my database to insert my result in that, then declare it as output in my stored procedure.

Is there another suggestion?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for your note man, but it is not `sp` it is `_sp` which would make a difference between microsoft own use! does it have a problem? I knew about `sp` but I did not heard that `_sp` advised to be avoid.
sorry for my english :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be...

```
create procedure dbo._sp_checkId
@value dbo.type_first readonly
AS
begin

delete from @value
where Id in (select Id
             from dbo.tbl_first)
--This will return your output when you execute the procedure
             Select * from @value

             end
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo._sp_checkId TO public
GO

exec dbo._sp_checkId
```

Comment: i want to my output be a variable and be as my type_first, select * from @value at end of the sp is not suitable for my next move! thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try with SELECT statement at the end

```
create procedure dbo._sp_checkId
(
    @value dbo.type_first readonly
)
as
BEGIN
delete
from @value
where Id in
(
    select Id
    from dbo.tbl_first
)
GO
SELECT @value
END
```